# how to fix drag and drop in react?

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to make a drag and drop game but when i try to move an item it doesn't transfer.
In the browser console there are no errors, in the console where I start the application there are no errors either, I don't know what to do.
I don't know what else to say.

````
    const dragStartHandler = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
        alert('Вы не прошли капчу')
    }
    const dragLeaveHandler = (e: React.DragEvent) => {
        (e.target as Element).classList.remove('over')
    }
    const dragOverHandler = (e: React.DragEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        (e.target as Element).classList.add('over')
    }

    
    const dropHandler = (e: React.DragEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        (e.target as Element).classList.remove('over')
        if ((e.target as Element).id === currentId.toString()) {
            if (currentEnvelope.current) {
                (currentEnvelope.current as Element).classList.add('hide')
                alert('Капча пройдена!')
            }
            // сюда можешь написать отправку на бек
        } else {
            alert('Вы не прошли капчу')
            // toast.error('Вы не прошли капчу', {
            //     position: "top-right"
            // })
        }
    }
    console.log(currentId)
    return (
        <>
        

<div className="post">
<ToastContainer
            
            />
            <header className="post__header">
                <h3 className="title">

                </h3>
            </header>
            <main className="post__main">
                <img 
                    ref={currentEnvelope}
                    src={images[`envelope-${currentId}`]}
                    //src={require(`./assets/envelope${currentId}.png`)} 
                    alt="current envelope" className="current__envelope" 
                    id={`${currentId}`} 
                    draggable='true' 
                    onDragStart={(e) => dragStartHandler(e)}
                />

                <div className="boxes">
                    <img 
                        src={require(`./assets/box1.png`)} 
                        alt="box" 
                        className="box" 
                        id="1"
                        onDrop={(e) => dropHandler(e)}
                        onDragOver={(e) => dragOverHandler(e)}
                        onDragLeave={(e) => dragLeaveHandler(e)}/>```
````

Comment: Fundamentally you are not allowed to write directly to dom nodes in React so your calls to `classList.add`  are not valid and will lead to undetermined behaviour. That stuff has to all be managed by React state and interpolating the classes in JSX. Likely those classes get wiped out the second React re-renders. Regardless usually folks use a library for this like https://docs.dndkit.com/ or https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd.

Comment: The thing is that the element doesn't even want to be moved, it doesn't come to class processing.

Comment: Nothing in your existing handlers attempts to move the element to a different place. That is not a built in part of the drag and drop web API -- its up the the developer to update the DOM when the handler is called.